# The value of my struct is not updated when passing a malloced pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on implementing a history for a shell. I have a struct that stores a command, and an array of these structs stores the history.

```
typedef struct command {
    char **arg;
    int num;
} cmd;
```

The code below correctly updates the history, printing out

> Cmd #1: ls -l
>
> Cmd #1: pwd
>
> Cmd #2: ls -l

```
int main() {
    char *arguments[3] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
    cmd *history = startHist();
    history = updateHist(arguments, history);
    printHistory(history);
    char *arg2s[2] = {"pwd", NULL};
    history = updateHist(arg2s, history);
    printHistory(history);
    free(history);
}

cmd* startHist() {
    cmd *ret = malloc(20*sizeof(cmd));
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        ret[i].arg = NULL;
        ret[i].num = -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

cmd* updateHist(char **args, cmd *hist) {
    for(int i = 19;i>0;i--) {
        hist[i] = hist[i-1];
    }
    hist[0].arg = args;
    if(hist[1].arg!=NULL) {
        hist[0].num = hist[1].num+1;
    } else {
        hist[0].num = 1;
    }
    return hist;
}

void printHist(cmd *hist) {
    int pos = 0;//index for iterating through commands
    while(hist[pos].arg!=NULL) {
        char* prstr = malloc(INIT_BUFFER*sizeof(char));//the string that will be printed
        *prstr = '\0';
        int index = 0;//index for iterating through arguments
        printf("Cmd #%d: ", pos+1);
        while(hist[pos].arg[index] != NULL) {
            printf("%s ", hist[pos].arg[index]);
            strcat(prstr, hist[pos].arg[index]);//concatenate the argument strings
            index++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        pos++;
        free(prstr);
    }
}
```

However, the following code fails to work. The string value of each cmd entry is instead replaced with the most recent command, although the int value functions properly.

Edit: code has been modified on recommendation. It should now run 3 loops of input.
Example output:

> ?: ls
>
> Cmd #1: ls
>
> ?: ls -a
>
> Cmd #1: ls -a
>
> Cmd #2: ls -a
>
> ?: exit
>
> Cmd #1: exit
>
> Cmd #2: exit
>
> Cmd #3: exit

Note that startHist(), printHist() and updateHist() are the same as above.

```
#include "stdio.h"//get from and print to console
#include "stdlib.h"//free and malloc
#include <string.h>//strtok

//Initial input buffer size. Will be expanded in getLine if needed.
const int INIT_BUFFER = 256;

typedef struct command {
    char **arg;
    int num;
} cmd;

//Function Declarations
char * getLine();//gets the input from the console and returns it
char ** splitLine(char *a);//splits the passed string into argument substrings
cmd* updateHist(char **args, cmd *hist);
void printHist(cmd *hist);
cmd* startHist();

void main() {
    //declare primary variables
    char *input;
    char **args;
    int retVal=3;
    cmd *history = startHist();
    do {//primary execution loop
        printf("?: ");//prompt for input
        input = getLine();
        args = splitLine(input);
        history = updateHist(args, history);
        printHist(history);
        retVal--;
        free(input);
        free(args);
    } while(retVal);
    free(history);
}

char ** splitLine(char *input) {
    //variables for finding the number and length of the arguments
    int numArgs=1;//the number of args in the input(starts at 1, increases per space).
    int pos = 0;//the position as the input is iterated through
    //loop to find the number and length of the arguments
    while(input[pos]!='\0'){//until the end of the input is reached
        if(input[pos]==' '){//if the end of the argument is reached
            numArgs++;//increment argument counter
        }
        pos++;//increment the position counter
    }
    pos=0;//reset pos to reiterate through the input
    //create an array of arguments
    char* *argArray = malloc((1+numArgs)*sizeof(char*));
    char *temp = strtok(input, " \n\r\t");//get the first token from the string
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        argArray[pos] =temp;
        pos++;
        temp=strtok(NULL, " \n\r\t");
    }
    argArray[pos]=NULL;
    return argArray;
}

char * getLine() {
    int buffspace = INIT_BUFFER;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*INIT_BUFFER);
    int pos = 0;
    int c;//input 
    
    if(!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shell: Allocation Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    do {
        c=getchar();//get the next character
        
        if(c==EOF || c=='\n'||c=='\r') {
            buffer[pos]='\0';
            return buffer;
        } else {
            buffer[pos] = c;
        }
        pos++;
        
        if(pos>=buffspace) {
            buffspace += INIT_BUFFER;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, buffspace);
        }
    } while(c!=EOF);
    
    //the buffer should be returned before this point.
    //Print out an error and exit
    fprintf(stderr, "Shell: Assignment Error\n");
    return buffer;
}

cmd* startHist() {
    cmd *ret = malloc(20*sizeof(cmd));
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        ret[i].arg = NULL;
        ret[i].num = -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

cmd* updateHist(char **args, cmd *hist) {
    for(int i = 19;i>0;i--) {
        hist[i] = hist[i-1];
    }
    hist[0].arg = args;
    if(hist[1].arg!=NULL) {
        hist[0].num = hist[1].num+1;
    } else {
        hist[0].num = 1;
    }
    return hist;
}

void printHist(cmd *hist) {
    int pos = 0;//index for iterating through commands
    while(hist[pos].arg!=NULL) {
        char* prstr = malloc(INIT_BUFFER*sizeof(char));//the string that will be printed
        *prstr = '\0';
        int index = 0;//index for iterating through arguments
        printf("Cmd #%d: ", pos+1);
        while(hist[pos].arg[index] != NULL) {
            printf("%s ", hist[pos].arg[index]);
            strcat(prstr, hist[pos].arg[index]);//concatenate the argument strings
            index++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        pos++;
        free(prstr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not productive to debug incomplete code as the problem may not even be in what is shown. For example, what does `getLine` do? How do we know it's not returning static memory or worse, a local variable?

Comment: @kaylum Sorry about that. I updated the code so it runs independently now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are just storing pointers in your `cmd` data structure and not the pointed at strings and arrays.  That means you end up saving pointers to local variables after they go out of scope, which leads to undefined behavior.